# Any idea of a similar Charting library? - Google Interactive Charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, google-visualization

the charts in question are the [Interactive Geo Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html)

I can't seem to find any alternatives.

---

Any ideas?

Comment: nope, why would you want something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [IBM ILOG Jviews](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/websphere/products/visualization/) good performance and very flexible.